# Is it wrong to use other users' suggestions in your answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes when I provide an answer that I'm not *entirely* educated about, for example I might leave out a rather vital piece of information that could change the information in the answer, other users comment saying something along the lines of "this is outdated" or "this (link) should shed some extra details on this."

For example [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/181704/what-is-the-maximum-paragon-level/181705#181705) regarding a new levelling system in Diablo 3, I provided a reference to an old system. A user then commented providing an up-to-date reference, which I then added to my question.

Even though I credited the other user for the link, I still kinda felt bad about it. Should I have instead suggested he provide his own answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No it isn't. It's actually a good thing. As long as you give credit where credit is due (which you absolutely did), incorporating comments is perfectly acceptable. Comments are for improving answers. Adding credit into the post itself isn't alsways needed either, just some kind of recognition that you used the comment works too [a response in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17218660#17218660) works if you get [a comment in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17218522#17218522), a comment in reply works for a comment.

If I post something in a comment it's because I feel it doesn't deserve an answer of itself or I don't have time to make it a full answer, and by the time I'll have time I'd probably forget about it.

If you are going to copy paste someone else's comment as a new answer (it happens) then I suggest making your answer community wiki, if you think you'd be running away with someone else's rep.

Comment: Just to add that I've seen this question on meta.rpg.stackexchange and I suspect it turns up on almost every meta site. The consensus was the same there, building the best possible answer is always a good thing. Never feel bad about provided a good answer, credit is appreciated.

Comment: It's also nice to have the answer be in the answer and not littered through the comments of an answer.